# Wrap images from text field into image_tag

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I would like to create a helper or change the model.rb to behave like:

Post model has a text field, which contains urls, all separated with new lines.
On create or update, rails scans this field, when it finds url like:

```
http://i.imgur.com/imanimage.png
http://i.imgur.com/anotherimage.png
```

Then it leaves them as is, but in the show action  it renders them as:

```
= image_tag('http://i.imgur.com/imanimage.png', class: 'my-image-class')
= image_tag('http://i.imgur.com/anotherimage.png', class: 'my-image-class')
```

Probably a helper method could do this.

Comment: Comment moved to answer -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20824707/wrap-images-from-text-field-into-image-tag/20825151#20825151

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does the text field store anything else but the urls? If it does, you should consider creating helper using regex to get all urls and change these to `<img src=''/>`,

If not, you can use in haml/erb file.

```
Model.text.each_line do |m| 
  image_tag(m, class: 'my_img') 
end
```

Reference: http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/String.html#method-i-lines

Answer (score 0):

If you're saving these URLs in your database, you it should be quite a simple procedure:

```
#app/models/image_url.rb
Class ImageURL < ActiveRecord::Base
end

#app/controllers/image_urls_controller.rb
def show
    @url = ImageURL.find(params[:id])
end

#app/views/image_urls/show.html.erb
<%= image_tag(@url, class: 'my-image-class')
```

If you add some more context to your question, I'll be able to give you a more refined answer!

Comment: I would like to save all these urls into a simple field, so I don't need to create a model for each url.

Comment: You don't need to create a model for each URL - you'll put each URL into a database, which is handled _by_ a model (in our case, the `ImageURL` model)